# How to apply EF Core DB schema from a shared class library NuGet package

Tags: entity-framework-core, nuget

Let's say I have a class that extends DBContext (hereby called DBContext for simplicity) defined in a shared library plus an extension method to simplify adding this DBContext to dependency injection (given a configuration variable, it will generate a connection string to the database).

How would I go about applying the database schema? From the shared library? From a binary that consumes this library?

It's my understanding that when you apply a schema to a database a migrations folder is created and I want one canonical place where these migrations go.

If I run `dotnet ef database update` from the shared library, how does it know where the database is if I'm not providing configuration? Where would I provide configuration (like *which* database server and *what* credentials)

This shared library will likely be used by many consumers, so having migration scripts on each project sounds like a bad idea. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Place the Connection String inside configuration for your Startup project (appsettings.json or other) and pass it to your extension method in your library.

Leave the Migrations in the library project with the `DbContext`. When you run `dotnet ef database update` you can provide separate `--project` (the project with your DbContext and Migrations) and `--startup-project` (the project that actually consumes your library) options.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#using-the-tools

> The startup project is the one that the tools build and run. The tools have to execute application code at design time to get information about the project, such as the database connection string and the configuration of the model. By default, the project in the current directory is the startup project. You can specify a different project as startup project by using the --startup-project option.